# RobotFramework: Drag And Drop Selenium2 Keyword seems not to work

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, drag, selenium2library

I'm testing web app (using RobotFramework with Selenium2Library) in which some drag and drop actions is needed at couple of points. I tried Drag And Drop keyword, but it's not working properly.

Since I can't pass the production app, I recreated problem using this page below:
https://html5demos.com/drag/

My code is:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${URL} =  https://html5demos.com/drag/

*** Test Cases ***

Prepare Browser
    Open_Browser  ${url}  browser=chrome
    Maximize Browser Window

Make Test
    #Drag And Drop  //*[@id="one"]  //*[@id="bin"]
    #Drag And Drop  //*[@id="two"]  //*[@id="bin"]
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Sleep  1

Close All
    Close Browser
```

Have tried it using both Python 2.7 and 3.6.

Output I get is **test shown as PASS**, but I can't see any real results of drag and drop action (both in my production app and sample page linked above). 
[Screenshot of drag and drop test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlyEm.jpg)

When I look into what happens in the browser during test I notice, that the object became *draggable* (quote "drag me" is added in brackets) but test stood for a log time. When mouse cursor is moved, test goes on int PASS mentioned above, but without real effect.

Tried on newest Chrome, Firefox, IE. Also tried with keywords **Mouse Down**, **Mouse Over**, **Mouse Up**, but with the same results.

Here is screenshot of log from execution report:
[Execution report screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NimlT.jpg)

I would appreciate any help or workaround to have it done correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the above answer and they weren't applicable to my use case and neither was the inbuilt function of selenium. Instead i implemented my own drag and drop keyword that is reusable. This works even for scenarios where in the angular js/ react js elements for example don't have an attribute called draggable set.

```
Drag And Drop
    [Arguments]     ${src}     ${intermediate}      ${tgt}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      ${ATTEMPTS}     ${LARGER_TIMEOUT}      Mouse Down   ${src}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      ${ATTEMPTS}     ${LARGER_TIMEOUT}      Mouse Over   ${intermediate}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      ${ATTEMPTS}     ${LARGER_TIMEOUT}      Mouse Over   ${tgt}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      ${ATTEMPTS}     ${LARGER_TIMEOUT}      Mouse Up     ${tgt}
```

The use of Wait until keyword succeeds helps with guaranteeing to a good extent that the process wont fail. You can find its documentation [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds). What the drag and drop does is literally press the mouse down move location and release it. I have additionally used an intermediate location to handle cases where it may fail but its not necessary.

To call the function simply use something like this -

```
Drag And Drop   ${XPATH1}  ${XPATH2}  ${XPATH3}
```

Answer (score 4):

From other posts on [so] it appears that this functionality doesn't work very well. For this reason most answers contain the advice to use JavaScript to create a solution. I've adapted the example found in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38889823/6152737) to work with Robot Framework:

**drag-n-drop.js**

```
var dataTransfer=
                {
                    dropEffect:'',
                    effectAllowed:'all',
                    files:[],
                    items:{},
                    types:[],
                    setData:function(format,data)
                    {
                        this.items[format]=data;
                        this.types.push(format);
                    },
                    getData:function(format)
                    {
                        return this.items[format];
                    },
                    clearData:function(format){}
                };
var emit=function(event,target)
                {
                    var evt=document.createEvent('Event');
                    evt.initEvent(event,true,false);
                    evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;
                    target.dispatchEvent(evt);
                };
                
var DragNDrop=function(src,tgt) {
    src = document.getElementById(src);
    tgt = document.getElementById(tgt);
    emit('dragstart',src);
    emit('dragenter',tgt);
    emit('dragover',tgt);
    emit('drop',tgt);
    emit('dragend',src);
    return true;
}
```

**drag-n-drop.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library  OperatingSystem    

Suite Setup       Open_Browser    ${url}    Chrome
Suite Teardown    Close Browser

*** Variables ***
${URL} =  https://html5demos.com/drag/

*** Test Cases ***
Make Test
    ${js}        Get File              drag-n-drop.js
    ${result}    Execute Javascript    ${js}; return DragNDrop("two", "bin");
    
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Sleep  1
```

Comment: I still need some help with it, since I do not know JavaScript well yet. How to change the code above, if what I want to have as an arguments of DragNDrop function are xpaths instead of div ids. In the application I test I don't have attributes like 'id' and I use xpath locator strategy (usually I use div class and text()). In above example, when I want to locate source div by xpath=//*[@id="one"] and target by xpath=[@id="bin"] I get ERROR: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent'  of null. How to change that JavaScript to be used in more universal?

Comment: I have xpath like this: 
SOURCE:  <div class="b-text b-text_ellipsis b-text_no-select b-text_white">Source Name</div>
DESTINATION:  <div class="b-text b-text_disabled">Drop here</div>
How would you try to get those ones?

Comment: This really is a new question. In addition, it is a question that has been asked before on [so] that a simple search on [JavaScript Cross xPath](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+cross+xpath) gives a number of results that should allow you to craft a solution that works for you.

Comment: Workaround for how to find a locator using xpath is adding following function to the script above and call it inside DragNDrop function. `function getElementByXpath(path) {return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;}`
And in DragNDrop: `src = getElementByXpath(src) tgt = getElementByXpath(tgt)`

Answer (score 1):

Try it out

```
 Drag And Drop Element
    [Arguments]     ${src}  ${tgt}

    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      ${ATTEMPTS}     ${LARGER_TIMEOUT}      Mouse Down   ${src}
    Sleep       1s
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      ${ATTEMPTS}     ${LARGER_TIMEOUT}      Mouse Out    ${src}
    Sleep       1s
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      ${ATTEMPTS}     ${LARGER_TIMEOUT}      Mouse Over   ${tgt}
    Sleep       1s
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      ${ATTEMPTS}     ${LARGER_TIMEOUT}      Mouse Up     ${tgt}
    Sleep       1s
```